# how to check dynamically created checkbox is checked using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  if(this.checked){
    if($(':checkbox:checked').length>1 && $('#qT').val()==1){
        $(this).prop( "checked", false );
    }
  }
});
```

this is the script to run
And html looks like below

```
<div class=row>....
<div class="isCorrect">
    <span>correct</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input mx-1"value="1">
</div>...</div>
<div class=row>....
<div class="isCorrect">
     <span>correct</span>
     <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input mx-1"value="1">
</div>...</div> 
etc etc
```

This code only checks the first check box. not any other..
I also tried

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  if(this.checked){
    if($(':checkbox:checked').length>1 && $('#qT').val()==1){
        $(this).prop( "checked", false );
    }
  }
}).triger(change);
```

and many other ways

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to prevent checking the check box if already any one is selected. depend on some other conditions also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because your event handler is created before the dynamic checkboxes are. To bypass this, you can bind an event handler to the whole document or, for better performance, to the parent that contains all your checkboxes :

```
$(document).on('change',"input[type='checkbox']",function () {

    // your code here...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

When dealing with dynamic elements you have to start your selector with an element that is not dynamic and is already on the page. I like using the on method when dealing with events because it gives you more control. As you see I then define the event and then select the dynamic element that I am targeting.

[Here is another reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery)

```
$("document").on("change", "input", function(){
  if($(this).checked && $('#qT').val()==1){
     $(this).prop( "checked", false );
  }
});
```